# What is the alternative to static style cells in storyboard?

Tags: ios

I cannot use static style UITableViewCells because of the storyboard restriction that the underlying controller must be a UITableViewController.

So how can I achieve the UI layout like the 'new contact' screen in the ios Contacts app?

In particular the phone numbers/email ('mobile', home) input: is there any existing API that draws the thin vertical divider? Or I have to create a nib?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen this done by having the top three fields be fake. Use a table view header which has the image view and the First/Last/Company be simple textfields. You put a pretty picture that looks like table cells behind First/Last/Company.